# Doctirine 2 Case Statement

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I use Doctirine 2 and zf2. How can i convert this sql query to dql. (Doctirine Query Language)

My product entity is here "Application\Entity\Product" I 've tried it but it doesn't work..

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT price_range, count(*) AS num
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN price >= 0 AND price <= 10 THEN '0-10'
             WHEN price >= 10 AND price <= 20 THEN '10-20'
             WHEN price >= 20 AND price <= 30 THEN '30-40'
             WHEN price >= 30 AND price <= 40 THEN '30-40'
             WHEN price >= 40 AND price <= 50 THEN '40-50'
             WHEN price >= 50 AND price <= 60 THEN '50-60'
             WHEN price >= 60 AND price <= 70 THEN '60-70'
             WHEN price >= 70 AND price <= 80 THEN '70-80'
             WHEN price >= 80 AND price <= 90 THEN '90-100'
             WHEN price >= 100 AND price <= 110 THEN '100-110'
             ELSE 'over 1000'
         END as price_range
FROM product
WHERE 1
) AS  price_summaries
GROUP BY price_range
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately you can't. Doctrine doesn't support `CASE`. And looking at your problem, I'm also unable to find an adequate other solution with DQL.

You can however use a [native query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html). Native queries are embedded raw SQL queries, basically an extension of `PDO`.

Native queries are of course generally discouraged, as they have two disadvantages:

1. You must do the hydration into Doctrine entities yourself, using [ResultSetMapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-resultsetmapping) (if you want the result of the query to contain ready-made entities instead of plain arrays/objects).
2. Native queries undermine the whole point of using a DBAL: you loose portability. (But, to be honest, most projects don't just switch their RDBMS, so it's a rather theoretical concern).

But if you need to have the above query executed, use a *native query* in this single case.

Comment: Doctrine support case statement but i have to use native query. you can look my answer. thank you.

Comment: Yeah, but if it's in a native query, then it's not DQL, as you asked in your question.

Comment: i've tried native query but it say me "native query doesn't support inheritance" ... so i do it with "$em->getConnection()->query( $sql )->fetchAll()"

Answer (score 0):

Doctirine support case statement.

This works

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (p.price >= 0 AND p.price <= 10) THEN '0-10'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 10 AND p.price <= 20) THEN '10-20'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 20 AND p.price <= 30) THEN '30-40'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 30 AND p.price <= 40) THEN '30-40'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 40 AND p.price <= 50) THEN '40-50'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 50 AND p.price <= 60) THEN '50-60'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 60 AND p.price <= 70) THEN '60-70'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 70 AND p.price <= 80) THEN '70-80'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 80 AND p.price <= 90) THEN '90-100'
                             WHEN (p.price >= 100 AND p.price <= 110) THEN '100-110'
                             ELSE 'over 1000'
                         END as price_range
                        FROM \Application\Entity\Product p
```

But this doesn't work, i think i should try native query

```
SELECT price_range, count(*) AS num
                    FROM
                    (SELECT CASE WHEN (p.price >= 0 AND p.price <= 10) THEN '0-10'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 10 AND p.price <= 20) THEN '10-20'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 20 AND p.price <= 30) THEN '30-40'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 30 AND p.price <= 40) THEN '30-40'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 40 AND p.price <= 50) THEN '40-50'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 50 AND p.price <= 60) THEN '50-60'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 60 AND p.price <= 70) THEN '60-70'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 70 AND p.price <= 80) THEN '70-80'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 80 AND p.price <= 90) THEN '90-100'
                         WHEN (p.price >= 100 AND p.price <= 110) THEN '100-110'
                         ELSE 'over 1000'
                     END as price_range
                    FROM \Application\Entity\Product p
                    ) AS  price_summaries
                    GROUP BY price_range
```

Comment: If it's a native query, then it's *not* supported by Doctrine, but directly passed to your dababase server.